# Merging two sorted linked lists in python and returning a new linked_list without changing either of input linked lists

Tags: python, linked-list

As the title says, I would like to merge two sorted linked lists into a new linked list and return it. So for example, if **linked_list_1** has 2 nodes with values of **1** and **5** whereas **linked_list_2** has 1 node with value **2**, I would like to return a new linked list with the following values: 1, 2, 5.

My logic in solving this problem is to compare node data from linked_list_1 to node data from linked_list_2, starting from the head of each linked_list, and then adding the node that has the smallest data to the linked_list that I want return. I keep on doing this and moving through linked_list_1 and linked_list_2 until a node from either linked_list is None. Once it is None, I add the remaining nodes (either from linked_list_1 or linked_list_2) to the new linked_list that I want to return.

Here's the code that I wrote:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data=None, next_node=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next_node

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.data)


class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.length = 0
        self.head = None

    def print_list(self):
        node = self.head
        while node is not None:
            print(node, end=' ')
            node = node.next
        print('')

    def add_at_head(self, node):
        node.next = self.head
        self.head = node
        self.length += 1

    def remove_node_after(self, node):
        if node.next is not None:
            temp = node.next
            node.next = node.next.next
            temp.next = None
            self.length -= 1

    def remove_first_node(self):
        if self.head is None:
            return
        temp = self.head
        self.head = self.head.next
        temp.next = None
        self.length -= 1

    def print_backward(self):
        def print_nodes_backward(node):
            if node.next is not None:
                print_nodes_backward(node.next)
            if node is not None:
                print(node, end=' ')

        if self.head is not None:
            print_nodes_backward(self.head)

        print('')


def merge_linked_lists(linked_list_1, linked_list_2):
    # merge two sorted linked lists into a new linked list
    ll = LinkedList()

    node1 = linked_list_1.head
    node2 = linked_list_2.head

    if node1 is None:
        return linked_list_2.print_list()
    if node2 is None:
        return linked_list_1.print_list()

    while node1 is not None and node2 is not None:
        if node1.data == node2.data:
            ll.add_at_head(node1)
            ll.add_at_head(node2)
            node1 = node1.next
            node2 = node2.next

        elif node1.data < node2.data:
            ll.add_at_head(node1)
            node1 = node1.next

        else:
            ll.add_at_head(node2)
            node2 = node2.next

    while node1 is not None:
        ll.add_at_head(node1)
        node1 = node1.next
    while node2 is not None:
        ll.add_at_head(node2)
        node2 = node2.next

    return ll.print_backward()
```

After running the code, I am getting an infinite loop and I am not sure why this is happening. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-two-sorted-linked-lists/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was because your `add_at_head()` was actually modifying the `.next` of the current node being added.

Because of this, when you add a node with an existing `.next` in the 3rd linked list, the `.next` is overridden, causing the infinite loop at the 3rd while when it keeps linking the 1st node in the linked list and the new node together, which, already has a `.next`

To solve the issue, you can create a copy of the node being processed in the `add_at_head()` and that should solve the issue, like so:

```py
    def add_at_head(self, node):
        new_node = Node(node.data)
        new_node.next = self.head
        self.head = new_node
        self.length += 1
```

Comment: Nice catch! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data=None, next_node=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next_node

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.data)


class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.length = 0
        self.head = None
        # add next node at this position
        self.add_at_this_position = None

    def print_list(self):
        node = self.head
        while node is not None:
            print(node, end=' ')
            node = node.next
        print('')

    def add_at_head(self, node):
        # if head is none create a new node
        if self.head == None:
            self.head = Node(data=node.data)
            self.add_at_this_position = self.head
            return
        # adding a new node
        self.add_at_this_position.next = Node(data=node.data)
        self.add_at_this_position = self.add_at_this_position.next
        self.length += 1

    def remove_node_after(self, node):
        if node.next is not None:
            temp = node.next
            node.next = node.next.next
            temp.next = None
            self.length -= 1

    def remove_first_node(self):
        if self.head is None:
            return
        temp = self.head
        self.head = self.head.next
        temp.next = None
        self.length -= 1

    def print_backward(self):
        def print_nodes_backward(node):
            if node.next is not None:
                print_nodes_backward(node.next)
            if node is not None:
                print(node, end=' ')

        if self.head is not None:
            print_nodes_backward(self.head)

        print('')


def merge_linked_lists(linked_list_1, linked_list_2):
    # merge two sorted linked lists into a new linked list
    ll = LinkedList()

    node1 = linked_list_1.head
    node2 = linked_list_2.head

    if node1 is None:
        return linked_list_2.print_list()
    if node2 is None:
        return linked_list_1.print_list()

    while node1 is not None and node2 is not None:
        if node1.data == node2.data:
            ll.add_at_head(node1)
            ll.add_at_head(node2)
            node1 = node1.next
            node2 = node2.next

        elif node1.data < node2.data:
            ll.add_at_head(node1)
            node1 = node1.next

        else:
            ll.add_at_head(node2)
            node2 = node2.next

    while node1 is not None:
        ll.add_at_head(node1)
        node1 = node1.next
    while node2 is not None:
        ll.add_at_head(node2)
        node2 = node2.next

    return ll.print_backward()
    

def create_linked_list(data):
    ll = LinkedList()
    for i in data:
        node = Node(data=i)
        ll.add_at_head(node)
    return ll
    
linked_list_1 = create_linked_list([1,7, 8])
linked_list_2 = create_linked_list([5, 6, 11])
merge_linked_lists(linked_list_1, linked_list_2)
```

You need to change your add_at_head function and everything will work.